# Twitter + Facebook automated posting from another site

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, twitter, mean-stack

For a site I am working on using mean stack, users that have claimed an organization on the site want to have reviews that are posted on the site to automatically post to Facebook and twitter.

A user on the site that is an owner of an organization on the site would have the option to connect to the organization's Facebook and twitter accounts and save that connection to the organization profile. Then whenever a review comes through on the site, that review is auto posted to the social media sites.

This would mean that the site would have social media credentials saved in the DB for all organizations so the site can auto post when new reviews are posted for target organizations with social media connections on the profile.

Other than prompting the user to save the facebook username and password (prob breaks some auth rules), I'm not sure which direction to go in. social media tokens will expire, and articles related to social media connections are related to auto sign in.

I'm not sure if this is possible for Facebook given a change to facebook policy updates (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/) but not sure if it's related to this?

Maybe this is not possible or advised as this could be a security concern?

Comment: There is no way to post reviews on Facebook using the API

Comment: Thanks for the prompted response @WizKid So it's not allowed to save Facebook credentials or some long lived token to a website's server where the website can now post content to the facebook user's account?

Comment: Saving credentials are not allowed. Long lived tokens exists. They are valid for 60 days. You are not allowed to post automatically without the user knowing that it will happen.

Comment: looks like http://reviews.io has automatic posting to a facebook page through an iframe.  This was the example I was looking for. Looks like an iframe a facebook user would allow someone to post too: https://support.reviews.io/en/article/installation-facebook-reviews#connecting-reviewsio-and-facebook

Answer (score 0):

looks like reviews.io has automatic posting to a facebook page through an iframe. This was the example I was looking for. Looks like an iframe a facebook user would allow someone to post too: https://support.reviews.io/en/article/installation-facebook-reviews#connecting-reviewsio-and-facebook